# Read Registry Value, cast as String

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to read a REG_SZ value from the registry, then convert it to a string for later use.

I read it from the registry using

```
RegistryKey key
ArrayList m = new ArrayList();
if(Environment.is64BitOperatingSystem)
   key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
else
   key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);

if(key != null)
{
  object o = key.openSubKey(SOFTWARE\\xx\\yy\\zz).GetValue("Version")
  if (o != null)
    m.add(o.toString())
}
```

However, when I do this, an exception is thrown, saying

```
Application:abc.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidCastException
```

Is there a problem with the way I'm trying to cast this registry value?
I need it as a string to manipulate and compare.

Comment: Is your registry variable of the type REG_SZ? [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Also, I don't think `o as string` would even through an exception, it would just return `null` if the cast failed. Your issue is likely somewhere else (perhaps in Version constructor)? A better stack trace and code that is closer to the actual code you are running is probably needed to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Yes! it's a REG_SZ called "Version"

Comment: Fixed! Looks like it wasn't the cast to string that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! Looks like it wasn't the cast to string that was the problem.
I was trying to add the

```
o.toString()
```

to an `ArrayList` and adding the `string` to the `ArrayList` was causing the cast problem.

Thanks!